# Getting Owner information for custom object within apex

Tags: apex, soql, debugging

```
Public Clinic_Patient__c patient{get;set;}
Public Clinic_Patient__c  patient_owner{get;set;}
Public String SurgeryID{get;set;}


SurgeryID = System.currentPageReference().GetParameters().get('SurgeryID');
patient = [SELECT Patient_Name__c FROM Clinic_Patient__c where Id = :SurgeryID];
patient_owner = [SELECT Owner.Name, Owner.firstname, Owner.email FROM Clinic_Patient__c where Id = :SurgeryID][0];
```

My sample code is as above. When I do

```
System.debug(patient_owner)
```

all I see is just the OwnerID, and the ID (I do not see Name, firstname or email). Does anyone know what's happening? I have verified that those things exists and that it should not be null or empty for that specific SurgeryID

When I try

```
System.debug(patient.Owner)
```

as suggested below, I get the error of

```
common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Clinic_Patient__c.Owner
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to debug specific parent fields, you can debug the parent itself:

```
Clinic_Patient__c patient = [
    SELECT Owner.Name, Owner.Email FROM Clinic_Patient__c
    WHERE ...
];
system.debug(patient.Owner);
```

Or you can serialize the patient:

```
system.debug(JSON.serialize(patient));
```

Or you can debug the fields individually:

```
system.debug(patient.Owner.Name));
system.debug(patient.Owner.Email));
```

Comment: I've updated the question including the debugging step. Do you know what it means? I've tried googling about but have found nothing

Comment: @user You need to make sure you query for any fields you then de-reference. You would use `patient_owner` from your original example, or just add all the fields to your `patent` query. The error message itself is quite descriptive.

Comment: I'm so sorry. In all honesty I skimmed the first part of your code and missed adding in the Owner.Name and Owner.Email into the patient querying. I thought the owner addon was an error on some other part of the code